# undefined method `map' for string in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, slim-lang

In my Rails app, I'm trying to get links of events tagged with specified tags in my `events#index` view. In order to make them linked with `link_to`, I got the error below:

```
undefined method `map' for "fgssgf,sfgdsfg,dsgfsdgf,sgfdsg":String` error
  app/views/events/index.html.slim:17:in `block in _app_views_events_index_html_slim__...'
```

Here are files related with this issue:

`index.html.slim`:

```
table.table.table-bordered
  thead
    tr
      th Title
      th Start date
      th End date
      th Location
      th Tags

  tbody
    - @events.each do |event|
      tr
        td = link_to event.title, event
        td = event.start_date
        td = event.end_date
        td = event.location
        td = event.all_tags.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') # line 17 here
```

`index` method in `events_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @events = Event.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @events = Event.all
  end
end
```

`all_tags` & `tagged_with` methods in `event.rb`:

```
def all_tags
  tags.map(&:name).join(",")
end

def all_tags=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(',').map do |t|
    Tag.where(name: t.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end

def self.tagged_with(name)
  Tag.find_by!(name: name).events
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below method

```
def all_tags
  tags.map(&:name).join(",") # here you are creating an string.
end
```

should be

```
def all_tags
  tags.map(&:name)
end
```

Your method as I said above creating an string, on which you attempted to call the `Array#map`
method. Which of-course not possible. Thus either you need to change the method, so that it returns *collection* instead of *string*. Or, if you don't want to change the method, then *split* the string back to array, so that you can call `#map` as below

```
 event.all_tags.split(",").map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }
```

Comment: Links have been fixed but now they are rendered like HTML-safe, not as exact links :( Probably, because of `slim` lingo...

Comment: @ekremkrc Little slow still I am in Rails.. :( You can ask a diff question now.. to get answer quickly..

Comment: Ok, I got it! At least, I've fixed `split/join` issue. Here's your tick: Grab it!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Arup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit)'s richtig answer; I've done these changes below:

`all_tags` from `event.rb`:

```
def all_tags
  tags.map(&:name).join(',') # return stays same
end
```

links part from `index.html.slim`:

```
td
  - event.all_tags.split(',').map do |t| # single-line could be done but this one is better
    = link_to t, tag_path(t)
```